# Problema side menu jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou tendo problema ao fechar o side menu no intelXDK, utilizo `JQuery` para fazer a abertura e o fechamento porem o problema está quando eu fecho, pois ele não mantem a `margin` do retângulo que criei, exemplo em imagens abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

JS de abrir e fechar o side menu:

```
uib_sb.toggle_sidebar($(".uib_w_43"));
```

CSS Card.

```
.card_Info {
  margin-top: -15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: 2%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 96%;
  height: 100px;
  .fecharPop{
    font-size: 21px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    color: #b1b1b1;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .card_Titulo{
    font-family: ARIAL-BLACK;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #34495e;
  }
  .card_Data{
    color: #7f8c8d;
  }
  .card_Local{
    width: 60%;
    color: #7f8c8d;
  }
  .card_Botao{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -85px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #7f8c8d;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    float: right;
    border: 5px solid #7f8c8d;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 5px;
    .botao_Icone{
      margin-left: 35%;
      margin-top: 28%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-size: 32px;
      color: white;

    }
  }
}
```

CSS SIDEMENU

```
.menu-side-bar {
  z-index: 9999;
  clear: both;
  .header-side-menu{
    background-color: rgb(236, 240, 241);
    height: 155px;
    vertical-align: center;
  }
  img{
        height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  .name-logado{
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    h10{
      font-size: 25px;
      font-family: Lato;
      color: rgb(127, 140, 141);
    }
  }
  .content-side-menu{
    .contat-titulo-side-menu{
      background-color: rgb(52, 73, 94);
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: TAHOMA;
      color: #ecf0f1;
      height: 25px;
      padding-top: 3px;
    }
    .content-content-side-menu{
      font-family: VERDANA;
      font-size: 17px;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      margin-left: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Poderia simular o problema utilizando o https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Nao sei utilizar mais tentarei so um minuto

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5raiwweyAS  ta ai porem nao funciona perfeito nao sei porque.